# iPhone 5 screen resize not adjusting

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have read a few of the posts, and was able to implement into most of my app, however the main screen does not fully show up on the iphone 5.  There is about a 1 inch space at the bottom that I cant seem to fix.

I have some images attached to clarify any questions.

The @2x images are loading properly, it seems the view is constrained to the smaller size which shows up fine on the simulator.

Any thoughts?

```
#import "Mainscreencantroller.h"
#import "OBShapedButton.h"
@interface Mainscreencantroller ()

@end

@implementation Mainscreencantroller
@synthesize delegate;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Everything in autosizing is selected (middle arrows and outside ones)

I noticed that the length and width here arent grayed out like all the other xib files.

Comment: You've tried to add an image, but didn't post the link ..

Comment: Assuming you have MainWindow.nib, edit it, click the window, and select "full screen at launch".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just finished doing an update for iPhone 5 support.  A good deal of my background images were center aligned and I need to to change them to top aligned to work properly for the the larger screen size.

Comment: sorry, can't post images until i get points (apparently).  top aligned is just clicking the top I bar in the autosizing?, or is that the block from the square above?    Thanks for the reply!

Comment: No, its in the attributes inspector, first item in the "View" section, labeled "Mode".  In the case of UIImageView (at least in how I had things set up in my case) I had to set the mode to Top and also, in the Size inspector, set the autosizing to be variable height.

Comment: This worked well, thanks!  It covered the bottom part of the screen that wasnt before, now i just nees to figure out how yo make the buttons fill up the rest of that space.  Thanks!!